# How to sort a set of squares one next to other in icreasing size order along the X axis in C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
internal class Square
    {
    private double m_Lenght ;
    private double m_PositionX ;
    private double m_PositionY ;
    public Square ( double p_Length )
        {
        m_Lenght = p_Length ;
        m_PositionX = 0 ;
        m_PositionY = 0 ;
        }
    public void SetPosition ( double p_PositionX , double p_PositionY )
        {
        m_PositionX = p_PositionX ;
        m_PositionY = p_PositionY ;
        }
    public double GetLenght ()
        {
        return m_Lenght ;
        }
    public static void OrganiseSquares ( List <Square> pio_Squares)
        {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
        }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some more detail to your question. What have you tried already? What problems are you encountering specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by *increasing size order along the X axis*? Should it be sorted by its x position or length or the combination of both based on some rules?

Comment: I need to place squares in X axis in icreasing order of their area/length.

Answer (score 2):

This code will set the position of each square such that they are layed from the shortest square to the longest along the X axis (including some spacing between them)

```
public static void OrganiseSquares(List<Square> pio_Squares)
{
    double xPosition = 0;
    double spacing = 15;
    foreach (var square in pio_Squares.OrderBy(sq=>sq.GetLenght())
    {
        square.SetPosition(xPosition, 0);
        xPosition += square.GetLenght() + spacing
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you got my problem...But I dont need any space between squares. Place the square at the right bottom point of previous square. Position of bottom left point of first square is at (0,0). Consider this... plz

Comment: I think we can just avoid the element 'spacing'....

Comment: Sure, if you don't want to put some fixed space between the squares, just take it out and it should be just fine. If you feel this answers your question, consider marking this answer as correct

Comment: I believe this will work....I need to check from home... I'm at net cafe.... anyway  I am thanking you my friends.....

Comment: When I compile it shows one ErrorError 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Square>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Square>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you should add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file. Let me know if you are not allowed to use LINQ, and I'll put together a sample that does the sorting the traditional way.

Answer (score 0):

without any further information, what I understood is you want order squares according to their width. Note that the code you provided has many problems;

```
internal class Square
{
    private double length;
    private double positionX;
    private double positionY;

    public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            return this.length;
        }
    }

    public Square(double p_Length)
    {
        length = p_Length;
        positionX = 0;
        positionY = 0;
    }
    public void SetPosition(double p_PositionX, double p_PositionY)
    {
        positionX = p_PositionX;
        positionY = p_PositionY;
    }

    public static List<Square> OrganiseSquares(List<Square> pio_Squares)
    {
        List<Square> squares = pio_Squares.OrderBy(q => q.Length).ToList();
        return squares;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point, which is to assing the coordinates (using SetPosition) after sorting the array. Also, you modified the function signature, so I don't think this is a valid answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program //class with main method that triggers the program execution
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Square> listOfSquares = new List<Square>(); // creating a List variable that could hold 'Square' type objects

        //adding 'Square' type objects into the List
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(12)); 
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(6));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(12));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(5));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(4));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(10));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(2));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(4));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(1));
        listOfSquares.Add(new Square(4));
        //invoking the static method 'OrganiseSquares()' from Square class in-order
        //to sort a set of squares one next to the other in increasing size order along the X axis.
        Square.OrganiseSquares(ref listOfSquares); 
    }
}
internal class Square
{
    private double m_S;
    private double m_PX = 0;
    private double m_PY = 0;

    public Square(double p_S) //constructor
    {
        m_S = p_S;
    }

    public void SetXPosition(double p_PX) // method to set the value of one of the data members m_PX
    {
        m_PX = p_PX;
    }

    public void SetYPosition(double p_PY) // method to set the value of one of the data members m_PY
    {
        m_PY = p_PY;
    }

    public double GetSide() // method to retrieve the value of one of the data members m_S
    {
        return m_S;
    }

    //Method Description:
    //The method OrganiseSquares gets a list of squares and modifies each square position 
    //so the Squares are placed one next to the other in increasing size order along the X axis.

    //Parameter Description:
    //pio_Squares - The list of Squares as input and output. For the output the Squares should be sorted from smaller to bigger and in the right position. All the squares are in position 0,0 initially.
    //return: The return value will be void as the imputed Square objects will be modified to set their position according to the algorithm.

    //There must not be any space between squares.

    public static void OrganiseSquares(ref List<Square> pio_Squares)
    {
        double nextXPosition = 0;

        SortBySide(ref pio_Squares); // Sorts the List of objects in the increasing order based on the value stored by 'm_S' data member of each Square type object

        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < pio_Squares.Count; iterator++) // iterate through the sorted list of objects and set the values for m_PX and m_PY accordingly
        {
            if(iterator==0)
            {
                pio_Squares[iterator].SetYPosition(pio_Squares[iterator].GetSide());
                nextXPosition = pio_Squares[iterator].GetSide();
            }

            else
            {
                pio_Squares[iterator].SetXPosition(nextXPosition);
                pio_Squares[iterator].SetYPosition(pio_Squares[iterator].GetSide());
                nextXPosition += pio_Squares[iterator].GetSide();
            }
        }

        foreach(Square square in pio_Squares) //iterates through the sorted list of objects to print the values stored in each data member of every object sequentially
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Side:{0} X:{1} Y:{2}",square.GetSide(),square.m_PX,square.m_PY);
        }
    }

   //Method Description:
   //Method that implements Bubble sorting algorithm to sort the List of objects in the increasing order 
   //based on the value stored by 'm_S' data member of each Square type object

   //Parameter Description:
   //pio_Squares - - The list of squares as input and output. For the output the squares should be sorted from smaller to bigger and in the right position.

   public static void SortBySide(ref List<Square> pio_Squares) 
   {
    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < pio_Squares.Count; iterator++)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < pio_Squares.Count - 1; index++)
        {
            if (pio_Squares[index].GetSide() > pio_Squares[index + 1].GetSide())
            {
                Swap(ref pio_Squares, index);
            }
        }
    }
   }

   //Method Description:
   //Method that swaps 2 Square type objects from the List that would be passed by reference

   //Parameter Description:
   //pio_Squares - - The list of squares as input and output. For the output the squares having index & index+1 needs to be swapped

   public static void Swap(ref List<Square> pio_Squares, int index)
   {
    Square temp = pio_Squares[index];
    pio_Squares[index] = pio_Squares[index+1];
    pio_Squares[index+1] = temp;
   }

}
```